# iOS 13 Custom Fonts download and installation

Tags: swift, fonts, core-text, ios13

I want to download a font using CoreText API but it works in `iOS 12`, NOT available on `iOS 13`.

There is a [demo project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/DownloadFont/Listings/DownloadFont_ViewController_m.html) from Apple in 2013. But The API it used seems to be private since iOS 13.

```swift
/*     
    @param      progressBlock
Callback block to indicate the progress.
Return true to continue, and return false to cancel the process.
This block is called on a private serial queue on OS X 10.15, iOS 13, and later.
     
*/

@available(iOS 6.0, *)
public func CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler(_ descriptors: CFArray, _ mandatoryAttributes: CFSet?, _ progressBlock: @escaping CTFontDescriptorProgressHandler) -> Bool
```

As the documentation declared:

> This block is called on a private serial queue on OS X 10.15, iOS 13, and later.

Here is my code for font download:

```swift
let fontName = "STXingkai-SC-Light"
let attributes = [kCTFontNameAttribute : fontName] as CFDictionary
let fontDescription = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes(attributes)
// create font font descriptor and add it in an array
let descs = [fontDescription] as CFArray
CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler(descs, nil) { (state, progressParamater) -> Bool in
    let progressValue = (progressParamater as Dictionary)[kCTFontDescriptorMatchingPercentage]?.doubleValue
    
    switch state {
    case .didBegin: print("didBegin")
    case .didFinish: print("didFinish")
    case .willBeginDownloading: print("willBeginDownloading")
    case .didFinishDownloading:
        print("--> download finish")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fontLabel.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: 20)
        }
    case .downloading:
        print("downloading#####\(progressValue ?? 0.0)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.progressView.progress = Float(progressValue ?? 0.0)
        }
    case .didFailWithError:
        if let error = (progressParamater as Dictionary)[kCTFontDescriptorMatchingError] as? NSError {
            print(error.description)
        } else {
            print("ERROR MESSAGE IS NOT AVAILABLE")
        }
        
    default: print(String(reflecting: state))
    }
    
    return true
    
}
```

I tried this API on iOS 12 and Xcode 10, everything works fine and I can download a font with **provided fontName**.

[image: font download successfully]

But, when I use this one on `Xcode 11 Version 11.0 beta 6 (11M392q)` and `macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A526h)`, something went wrong and that method is no longer effective. And I got some output:

```
didBegin
__C.CTFontDescriptorMatchingState
didFinish
done
"Error Domain=com.apple.CoreText.CTFontManagerErrorDomain Code=303 \"0 
font descriptors do not have information to specify a font file.\"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=0 
font descriptors do not have information to specify a font file.
```

> 0 font descriptors do not have information to specify a font file

The state will only have didBegin and didFinish, not calling downloading.

[WWDC19 seeesion 227](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/) has announced that `CTFontManagerRegisterFontDescriptors(fontDescriptors:scope:enabled:registrationHandler:)` is available and something about font management. But the source code from the session pdf is not clearly and I've tried, got an other error:

```
done
[Error Domain=com.apple.CoreText.CTFontManagerErrorDomain Code=306 "The file is not in an allowed location. It must be either in the application’s bundle or an on-demand resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The file is not in an allowed location. It must be either in the application’s bundle or an on-demand resource., CTFontManagerErrorFontURLs=(
    "http://iweslie.com/fonts/HanziPenSC-W3.ttf"
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=Font registration was unsuccessful.}]
done
```

Here is my code referencing from WWDC19 session 227:

```swift
let urlString = "http://iweslie.com/fonts/HanziPenSC-W3.ttf"
let url = URL(string: urlString)! as CFURL
let fontURLArray = [url] as CFArray
CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs(fontURLArray, .persistent, true) { (errors, done) -> Bool in
    if done {
        print("done")
    }
    print(errors as Array)
    return true
}
```

And got the error:

> Error Domain=com.apple.CoreText.CTFontManagerErrorDomain Code=306
>
> "The file is not in an allowed location. It must be either in the application’s bundle or an on-demand resource."

Comment: Yep, I figured it out at last, thank you

Comment: Another cryptic undocumented Apple API. Can't download from a file, can't download from an external url. Only bundle resources or on-demand resources. Sigh...

Answer (score 3):

**For other people looking for a solution for iOS 13**
The easiest way to do it is probably using Apple Bundle and the 'new' *CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs* api.
Just gather all your urls in a list by utilizing Bundle.main.url:

```
let fontUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "ttf")
```

Then just register your fonts:

```
CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs([fontUrl] as CFArray, .persistent, true) { (errors, done) -> Bool in
        if(done) {
            print("Done")
        }
        print(errors as Array)
        return true
    }
```

If you're using another solution and having problems with the font name it might be xcode which is at fault. A tip I saw in another thread for figuring out what xcode is naming your fonts are:

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
    }
```

Also remember to enable *Install Fonts* capability under the *Signing & Capabilities* in your project settings.

Comment: to use this line, I need to do on-demanded resource download right?

Comment: No. That is the other way to go. Actually, when I tested this I tried to make them on-demand the first time. When adding the resource tags, the files disappeared from the Apple Bundle. So be sure to remove the resource tags for the files you want to do this with. Be sure to add your files as Bundle Resources though. You can do that under "Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Add your files". If you have a lot of files you might be better off using on-demand resources, and fetching from an external server.

Comment: Is the Install Fonts capability just for enrolled Developers? Apples Website on the topic doesn't list it https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/

Answer (score 0):

I have facing the same problem. and I finaly found this.

https://juejin.im/post/5aebd428f265da0ba266d897

the problem is you are using the wrong font postscriptname. the correct font name is "STXingkaiSC-Light".

I have test this on xcode 12, iOS 13 simulator.

you can find the correct font postscript name using "Font BooK.app".